Find a word with three consecutive double letters using Python
This is a question from Think Python: How to Think Like a Computer Scientist by Allen B. Downey
Give me a word with three consecutive double letters. I’ll give you a couple of words that almost qualify, but don’t. For example, the word committee, c-o-m-m-i-t-t-e-e. It would be great except for the ‘i’ that sneaks in there. Or Mississippi: M-i-s-s-i-s-s-i-p-pi. If you could take out those i’s it would work. But there is a word that has three consecutive pairs of letters and to the best of my knowledge this may be the only word. Of course there are probably 500 more but I can only think of one. What is the word? Write a program to find it.
My code doesn't work so I checked the solution but still have questions about the solution.
Question 1: This is my code,but the output is <built-in method strip of str object at .....> instead of the words, how should I improve this to answer the question?
fin = open('words.txt.py')
lines = fin.readline()
def carplay1(word):
    for lines in fin:
        word = lines.strip
        return word
    i = 0
    j = i+1
    while j<len(word):
        for check in range(3):
            if word [i] != word[j]:
                return False
            else:
                i = i+1
                j = j+1

    print(word)

print(carplay1(word))

Question 2: I've tested the given code with the word ('abbcdeeffgg') , even though it is not a word existing in the dictionary but I wanted to make sure the code in the solution can test word with three consecutive double letters at the back of the word. But the output is False.
I think the problem lies on the line "i = i + 1 -2*count"
How should I correct the code?
def is_triple_double(word):
    i = 0
    count = 0
    while i<len(word)-1:
        if word [i] == word [i+1]:
            count = count+1
            if count == 3:
                return True
            i = i + 2
        else:
            i = i + 1 - 2*count
            count = 0
        return False
print(is_triple_double('abbcdeeffgg'))


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read tag descriptions before using tags. From [tag:python-3.x]: "DO NOT USE UNLESS YOUR QUESTION IS FOR PYTHON 3 ONLY. Always use alongside the standard [python] tag."

You simply have a problem with the nesting of your return statement. After the if-condition, you always go to "return False".
If you move the return statement outside of the while-loop, your function returns "True".
def is_triple_double(word):
    i = 0
    count = 0
    while i<len(word)-1:
        if word [i] == word [i+1]:
            count = count+1
            if count == 3:
                return True
            i = i + 2
        else:
            i = i + 1 - 2*count
            count = 0
    return False 


print(is_triple_double('abbcdeeffgg'))  # Returns True

